Typesense, disabling the search Analytics for specific routes in Laravel
I'm using Laravel with typsesnse as the search driver for Scout,
I want a way to disable the search analytics for some routes for example in my case i want all the API routes to be excluded from the search analytics i only want the the result without saving the query
according to typesens docs there is bo built in way to do this

they add this functionality in version 27.0.rc30
you can simply do this:
$events = Event::search($search)
             ->options(['enable_analytics' => false])
             ->paginate(10);

